# How do I reinstall all Windows modern app completely from ISO?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-8-apps

Long story short, I ended up deleting some of the files from `C:\Windows\InfusedApps\` and `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`.

Now I am hoping if there is a way to completely reinstall all the apps from the Windows ISO.

I know there is an option to "Reset your PC". But I want to avoid that and reinstall only the modern apps

Answer (score 3):

You can completely reinstall all the modern apps by following these steps:

1. Open **Start Menu** and type **powershell**
2. **Right-click** on PowerShell and select "**Run as Administrator**" option. or you can press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** keys together to launch PowerShell as **Administrator**.
3. Please run this command:

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -register "$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode}
```

All modern apps contain this **appxmanifest.xml** **XML** file.

This command will take a few moments and will reinstall all built-in apps. Ignore any error message.

You may also need to **restart** after that.

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: You can accept this answer as helpful so that others facing the same issue can find this thread easily.   Thank you.

Comment: `appxmanifest.xml` happened to be one of the deleted file for me

Answer (score 1):

If all you did is removing some files from the folders that you mentioned, and nothing to complicate matters has happened, you should be able to extract those files from a Windows ISO. (In other words, the apps are still registered and only opening them—which I hope you didn't—generates an error.)

To do this, open a Windows installation image with the same version as the installed Windows. Open **I:\sources\install.wim** in [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/). Open one of the images (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or higher) and browser to Windows\InfusedApps. Extract and restore the files that you have deleted.

Another method is openning a Command Prompt with administrative privileges and issuing:

```
DISM /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:<Windows Setup path>
```

Replace  with a path to the Windows installation source.

Answer (score 0):

You may try restoring the folders from Volume shadow copy snapshots. Another option is to extract the folders from Windows 10 ISO.

To restore the volume shadow copies you may use [ShadowCopyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shadow_copy_view.html) or [PreviousFilesRecovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/previous_files_recovery.html), both are from Nirsoft.

If you have the Windows 10 ISO, matching the version and build of your current Windows installation, you can mount the ISO and extract the required files/folders by opening `install.wim` using 7-Zip or any other third-party archiving utility.

Shadow copy method might work out better in this case.